# Issue using Ansible's inventory plugin for AWS EC2

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the `aws_ec2` [inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html) for ansible. As I understand this is supposed to be the recommended method over the `ec2.py` inventory script. I got that gold nugget of information from [ansible's own blog post](https://www.ansible.com/blog/dynamic-inventory-past-present-future) and some random articles that mention it in the passing. However, as a novice to ansible, I find the documentation lacking.

3 problems I'm wandering about are:

1. A good way to pass secrets to the inventory definition file (I called it `hosts.aws_ec2.yml`). Jinja2 style of:

```
aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret }}"
```

produces a parse error.

As I understand this can be mitigating by setting env variables that will be picked up the plugin, but I'd like to get them from my ansible-vault encrypted file.

2. how do structure my host vars with this approach. So far, with a "static" inventory, I followed the structure outlined in this [blog post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible) -- one dir per environment. Any advice on how to deal with it using this plugin provided dynamic inventory?
3. is there a way I could specify ansible user and key for different inventory groups in a dynamic setting like this? Right now I set the globally, but I'd rather have the freedom to define them explicitly in the inventory.

Any advice is appreciated. Even a RTFM, as long as it's followed by some good reference links.

Comment: Interestingly enough to use the vault, you apparently vault the entire file https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55385

Comment: Ad. 3 is somewhat possible using the `compose` section https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/63895