# Using multiple SSH keys for different hosts with Ansible EC2 Inventory Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to use Ansible to install applications across a number of existing AWS EC2 instances which use a number of different SSH keys and usernames on different Linux OSes. Because of the changing state of the existing instances I am attempting to use Ansible's Dynamic Inventory via the `aws_ec2` inventory plugin as recommended.

I am able to group the hosts by `key_name` but now need to run the Ansible playbook against this inventory using the relevant SSH key and username according to the group, structured as the below example output from `ansible-inventory -i inventory.aws_ec2.yml --graph`:

```
@all:
  |--@_SSHkey1:
  |  |--hostnameA
  |  |--hostnameB
  |--@_SSHkey2:
  |  |--hostnameC
  |--@_SSHkey3:
  |  |--hostnameD
  |  |--hostnameE
  |  |--hostnameF
  |--@aws_ec2:
  |  |--hostnameA
  |  |--hostnameB
  |  |--hostnameC
  |  |--hostnameD
  |  |--hostnameE
  |  |--hostnameF
  |--@ungrouped:
```

I have tried creating a separate hosts file (as per the below) using the groups as listed above, providing the path to the relevant SSH key but I am unsure how you would use this with the dynamic inventory.

```
[SSHkey1]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/SSHkey1

[SSHkey2]
ansible_user=ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/SSHkey2

[SSHkey3]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/SSHkey3
```

This is not explained in the official Ansible documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html#inventory-plugins) and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html) but should be a common use case. A lot of the documentation I have found refers to an older method of using Dynamic Inventory using a python script (ec2.py) which is deprecated and so is no longer relevant (for instance [this AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/)).
I have found a similar unanswered question [here (Part 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625447/issue-using-ansibles-inventory-plugin-for-aws-ec2).

Any links to examples, documentation or explanations would be greatly appreciated as this seems to be a relatively new way of creating a dynamic inventory and I am finding it hard to locate clear, detailed documentation.

---

*Edit*

Using [group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) as suggested by @larsks in the comments worked. Was initially caught out by the fact that the SSH key names returned from the inventory plugin prepend an underscore so the group names need to be of the form `_SSHkey`.

Comment: I suspect you could solve this simply using [group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables).

Comment: I think you have the right idea.  Just be sure your dynamic inventory puts the hosts into the appropriate groups.

Comment: @larsks group variables worked with a minor issue which I have added to the original post. If you add your comment as an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use [group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) as suggested in the comments. SSH key names returned from the inventory plugin prepend an underscore so the group names need to be of the form `_SSHkey`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the ssh config file?  ~/.ssh/config. You can put specific host connection information there. Host, hostname,user,Identityfile are the four options you need

Host ec1
   Hostname 10.10.10.10
   User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ec1-ubuntu.rsa

Then when you ssh to 'ec1' , ssh will connect to host 10.10.10.10 as user ubuntu with the specified rsa key.  'Ec1' can be any name you like it does not have to be actual host name or ip or FQDN.  Make it match your inventory name.

Warning:: make certain file permissions for the directory ~/.ssh and the files within it are all 0600 (chmod -R 0600 ~/.ssh) and that the owner is correct or ssh will give you fits. On ubuntu the /var/log/auth.log will help with troubleshooting.